# Updating ComboBox ObservableCollection Binding in XAML from ViewModel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, telerik

I am working in WPF and have a view model `ModifiedReasonViewModel` that is my `DataContext` for an XAML view. The `ComboBox` doesn't display any of the 4 items that I can see in the data context when I'm debugging. I think it definitely has to do with the fact that I'm pulling the reason labels asynchronously. Any ideas on how to fix this?

When I test this code with just a list of test strings initialized in the constructor, it works as intended.

This is the `RadComboBox` what I'm currently working with in the XAML:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:ATMModifiedReasonViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
```

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Name="ReasonCmbo"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding ReasonLabels}" 
                     DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                     IsEditable="False"
                     Margin="2" 
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2">            
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

And this is the ViewModel code I'm working with:

```
public class ATMModifiedReasonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private List<LabelFileModel> _reasonLabels;

   public List<LabelFileModel> ReasonLabels { get { return _reasonLabels; } set { _reasonLabels = value; } }

   public ATMModifiedReasonViewModel(){
      GetReasonLabels();
   }

   public void GetReasonLabels()
   {
      LabelFileProvider lfProvider = new LabelFileProvider();
      LabelFileModelFilter filter = new LabelFileModelFilter() {LabelDefinition = "ModifiedReason"};
      lfProvider.GetFiltered(filter,10, getResult => GetReasonLabelsCallback(getResult));
   }

   private void GetReasonLabelsCallback(Func<IEnumerable<LabelFileModel>> getResult)
   {
       try
       {
            _reasonLabels = (List<LabelFileModel>) getResult();                
       }   
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
            Messenger.Default.Send(new UnhandledExceptionMessage(this, ex));
       }
   }
}
```

Thank you so much in advance for the help!

Comment: When binding the property to a View's control, ViewModel needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in order to notify the View of any property value changes

Comment: I implemented it earlier. I've added it back in and haven't had much luck still.

Comment: After some testing, it seems like instantiating the List and then adding items to it allowed the View to interpret the change and display the new items? Does this seem likely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reassign the `ReasonLabels` collection at runtime, you have to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-3.1) and raise the [`PropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1) event, otherwise the bindings will not notice the change.

Similarly, if you modify the collection itself, e.g. adding or removing items, the collection needs to implement [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1), which provides events to trigger an update in the user interface. The `List<T>` type does **not** implement this interface, use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netcore-3.1) instead. It automatically raises the [`CollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1) event, if the collection is modified and therefore triggers an update of bindings.

```
public class ATMModifiedReasonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private ObservableCollection<LabelFileModel> _reasonLabels;

   public ObservableCollection<LabelFileModel> ReasonLabels
   {
      get => _reasonLabels;
      set
      {
         if (_reasonLabels = value)
            return;

         _reasonLabels = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      } 
   }

   // ...your code here.

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

You also have to assign the `ReasonLabels` property instead of the backing field `_reasonLabels`, otherwise the property setter that triggers the `PropertyChanged` event will not be executed.

```
private void GetReasonLabelsCallback(Func<IEnumerable<LabelFileModel>> getResult)
{
   try
   {
      ReasonLabels = (List<LabelFileModel>) getResult();                
   }   
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Messenger.Default.Send(new UnhandledExceptionMessage(this, ex));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the *property* in your callback and raise the `PropertyChanged` event from the setter of it, or raise it the `PropertyChanged` event in the callback after you have set the backing field:

```
private void GetReasonLabelsCallback(Func<IEnumerable<LabelFileModel>> getResult)
{
    try
    {
        _reasonLabels = (List<LabelFileModel>)getResult();
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ReasonLabels )));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new UnhandledExceptionMessage(this, ex));
    }
}
```

Raising the event is required for the framework to know when to refresh the UI.